# How to escape commands in Makefile for killing process remotely?

Tags: bash, makefile, escaping

```
server_stop:
    ssh $(SERVER_USERNAME)@$(SERVER_HOSTNAME) \
        "kill $$(ps aux | grep '[p]ython abc-server' | awk '{print $$2}')"
```

This gives

```
bash: line 0: kill: (60403) - No such process
bash: line 1: 60364: command not found
```

I believe the brackets around p are not escaped correctly. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the command line, you don't need to use `ps` + `grep`. Use instead, `pgrep`.

```
server_stop:
    ssh $(SERVER_USERNAME)@$(SERVER_HOSTNAME) \
        'kill $$(pgrep -f "[p]ython abc-server")'
```

The `-f` allows you to pass the full command line to be found.

In order to avoid the shell evaluation to the command $$(pgrep -f "[p]ython abc-server"), surround it with single quotes, so the evaluation will happen in the target server.

Note: If possible, keep a start/stop script inside your server, so your ssh command will only call the script, avoiding the current issue.